# Install Ruby 2.0.0-p247 with rbenv

Tags: openssl, rbenv, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.0.0-p247 with rbenv and I keep getting the same error no matter what I do. Here's the command and response:

```
$ RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
Downloading ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz...
-> http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
Installing ruby-2.0.0-p247...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/v1/f8v8hqk12cdcdjwp660mz8fm0000gp/T/ruby-build.20130803134459.46575
Results logged to /var/folders/v1/f8v8hqk12cdcdjwp660mz8fm0000gp/T/ruby-build.20130803134459.46575.log

Last 10 log lines:
installing default gems:      /Users/scottmagdalein1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0 (build_info, cache, doc, gems, specifications)
                              bigdecimal 1.2.0
                              io-console 0.4.2
                              json 1.7.7
                              minitest 4.3.2
                              psych 2.0.0
                              rake 0.9.6
                              rdoc 4.0.0
                              test-unit 2.0.0.0
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

I know this question has been asked elsewhere, but those solutions still give me the same response regarding OpenSSL. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use CONFIGURE_OPTS instead of RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS.

Get the openssl directory location:

```
brew --prefix openssl
```

And here is the final command that I use to install 2.0.0-p247 on MacOS:

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl" rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
```

Comment: Correct! Also, my main issue was that openssl was out of date but brew wasn't telling me. uninstall and reinstall fixed it.